# Rails 3 - Unique subdomain and login for each user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to understand the models and the relations I need to have in order to let users register and choose a subdomain. I'm thinking in having an `Account` model and a `User` model using `Devise` as an authentication system. Being that the user `belongs` to an `Account` and an `Account` `has_many` `Users`.

Not sure if this is the best schema to accomplish what I want but, given what I've written, I'm struggling to understand how to make the e-mail unique for the Subdomain and only allow to login when in the subdomain. The `Admin` will then be able to invite other users to his account.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks
Donald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the work can be done in routes.rb:

```
module AppName
    class UserSubdomainConstraint
        def self.matches?( request )
            request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'
        end
    end
end

AppName::Application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users

    # THESE ARE THE ROUTES FOR YOUR MAIN SITE

    constraints( AppName::UserSubdomainConstraint ) do
        # THESE ARE THE ROUTES FOR USERS' SUBDOMAINS
    end
end
```

Then you can identify the user using the request.subdomain in your controller:

```
def index
    @user_account = User.where( :subdomain => request.subdomain ).account
end
```

Devise logins are going to be global across all sub-domains correct? So you can pretty much treat them as you would in any other app.

Comment: each user can only login in his own subdomain but, he can be added to more than 1 subdomain. The same email can be signed up for several subdomains.

Comment: Well really, you don't need the user to log into individual subdomains... you just need to allow access only to subdomains that belong to the user?

Comment: he can have access to different subdomains

Comment: You could always add to the self.matches conditional:

`&& current_user && current_user.subdomains.where( :name => request.subdomain ).any?`

Then the user would be given access to only their own subdomains, and login would be global (and simple) across the whole site.

I think maybe you're making this problem more complicated than it needs to be. :)